# How to conditionally sum across columns based on year in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, purrr

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(100023, 100024, 100034, 100064, 100054, 100032),
  year = c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000),
  n_1995_point_count = c(10, 5, 3, 8, 2, 1),
  n_1996_point_count = c(7, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1),
  n_1997_point_count = c(3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 0),
  n_1998_point_count = c(8, 4, 9, 2, 1, 0),
  n_1999_point_count = c(3, 4, 9, 2, 2, 0),
  n_2000_point_count = c(5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0)
)
```

I want to create a new column that sums across the n_XXXX_point_count columns conditionally based on the year in the "year" column, such that if the year is 1998, it sums across the n_1997_point_count,  n_1996_point_count, and n_1995_point_count columns (sums across the columns 1 year before itself).

So, I want the resulting output to look like this:

```
     id year n_1995_point_count n_1996_point_count n_1997_point_count n_1998_point_count n_1999_point_count n_2000_point_count cumulative_sum
1 100023 1995                 10                  7                  3                  8                  3                  5              0
2 100024 1996                  5                  6                  5                  4                  4                  2              5
3 100034 1997                  3                  2                  1                  9                  9                  3              5
4 100064 1998                  8                  4                  2                  2                  2                  1             14
5 100054 1999                  2                  3                  6                  1                  2                  4             12
6 100032 2000                  1                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0              2
```

Where the column "cumulative_sum" represents the sum for that year. As you can see, 1995 has a value of zero because there are no prior years, 1996 has a value of 5 because n_1995_point_count had a count of 5...etc. How can I do this leveraging tidyverse packages and grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for values that fit the condition with `str_extract` between a `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, year)) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_sum = sum(
    value[as.numeric(str_extract(name, "\\d{4}")) < year]), 
      .by = c(id, year)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 6 × 9
      id  year cumulative_sum n_1995_p…¹ n_199…² n_199…³ n_199…⁴ n_199…⁵ n_200…⁶
   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 100023  1995              0         10       7       3       8       3       5
2 100024  1996              5          5       6       5       4       4       2
3 100034  1997              5          3       2       1       9       9       3
4 100064  1998             14          8       4       2       2       2       1
5 100054  1999             12          2       3       6       1       2       4
6 100032  2000              2          1       1       0       0       0       0
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​n_1995_point_count, ²​n_1996_point_count,
#   ³​n_1997_point_count, ⁴​n_1998_point_count, ⁵​n_1999_point_count,
#   ⁶​n_2000_point_count
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple solution. We pivot longer, group by id and year, then add an additional row to each group with the cumulative sum data, before pivoting wider again.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(id, year)) %>%
    group_by(id, year) %>%
    mutate(vyear = as.numeric(str_extract(name, '([0-9]{4})')),
           dosum=vyear<year)%>%
    group_modify(~ add_row(.x, name='cumulative_sum', value=sum(.x$value[.x$dosum]))) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, year) %>%
    arrange(year)

      id  year n_1995_point_count n_1996_point_count n_1997_point_count n_1998_point_count n_1999_point_count n_2000_point_count cumulative_sum
   <dbl> <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>          <dbl>
1 100023  1995                 10                  7                  3                  8                  3                  5              0
2 100024  1996                  5                  6                  5                  4                  4                  2              5
3 100034  1997                  3                  2                  1                  9                  9                  3              5
4 100064  1998                  8                  4                  2                  2                  2                  1             14
5 100054  1999                  2                  3                  6                  1                  2                  4             12
6 100032  2000                  1                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0              2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse packages:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(cumulative_sum = map_dbl(accumulate(year - 1, c), ~ 
                                    select(df, matches(paste(.x, collapse = "|"))) |>
                                    slice(length(.x)) |>
                                    sum()))
```

Or using base R row and column indexing this could be shortened to:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(cumulative_sum = map_dbl(accumulate(year - 1, c), ~ sum(df[length(.x), grepl(paste(.x, collapse = "|"), names(df))])))
```

**How it works**

1. `accumulate` will create a list of the sequences specified:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1994

[[2]]
[1] 1994 1995

[[3]]
[1] 1994 1995 1996

[[4]]
[1] 1994 1995 1996 1997

[[5]]
[1] 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998

[[6]]
[1] 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999
```

2. We then collapse this into a regular expression to be used within the dplyr verb `matches`. When used within `select` this will return columns that match the regular expression. For example, `select(df, matches("1994|1995|1996"))` will return:

```
  n_1995_point_count n_1996_point_count
1                 10                  7
2                  5                  6
3                  3                  2
4                  8                  4
5                  2                  3
6                  1                  1
>
```

3. Lastly, we know the current row from the `length` of the list we are iterating over, so we simply `slice` that row (which returns a numeric vector) and `sum` that vector. Using `map_dbl` ensures we are returning a numeric vector for assignment to `cumulative_sum`.

**Output**

```
      id year n_1995_point_count n_1996_point_count n_1997_point_count n_1998_point_count n_1999_point_count n_2000_point_count cumulative_sum
1 100023 1995                 10                  7                  3                  8                  3                  5              0
2 100024 1996                  5                  6                  5                  4                  4                  2              5
3 100034 1997                  3                  2                  1                  9                  9                  3              5
4 100064 1998                  8                  4                  2                  2                  2                  1             14
5 100054 1999                  2                  3                  6                  1                  2                  4             12
6 100032 2000                  1                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0              2
```

---

In case you were interested here is how you could accomplish this in base R (note this relies on the columns and `year` being in ascending order):

```
count_vars <- grepl("\\d{4}", names(df))
df$cumulative_sum <- rowSums(lower.tri(df[, count_vars]) * df[, count_vars])
```